# UIStackView add arrange subviews inside tableView Cell didSet

Tags: swift, uitableview, uistackview

In my tableView Cell class, I use didSet method to setup my UI values and in there I have an array of string from api which I use to create an array of buttons and append it to a UIStackView

```
var pollDataInPollCell: PollModel? {
    didSet{
        if let pollOptions = pollDataInPollCell?.poll_detail {
           //sample pollOptions = ["Button1","Button2","Button3","Button4"]
            for index in pollOptions {
                let bt = UIButton(type: .system)
                bt.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
                bt.setTitle(index, for: .normal)
                optionBtnStackView.addArrangedSubview(bt)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my stackView outside of didSet

```
var optionBtnStackView: UIStackView = {
    let sv = UIStackView()
    sv.axis = .vertical
    sv.distribution = .fillEqually
    sv.spacing = 5
    return sv
}()
```

everything works great at launch however, when I scroll down and up, my stackview is adding 4 more buttons. It has 4 at launch and then 8 and then 12 and keep increasing by 4 whenever I scroll up and down my app. I know the problem is from tableView dequeueReusableCell but I couldn't find a way to fix this issue. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: This is happening because in didSet, you are adding views to your optionBtnStackView. When the cell is dequeued, its optionBtnStackView already has arranged views added to it and then on top of it, in didSet, you are adding more to it. Every time you cell is dequeued, try removing all the views from optionBtnStackView and then adding fresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code in your didSet

```
var pollDataInPollCell: PollModel? {
    didSet{
        for view in optionBtnStackView.subviews {
            optionBtnStackView.removeArrangedSubview(view)
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        if let pollOptions = pollDataInPollCell?.poll_detail {
           //sample pollOptions = ["Button1","Button2","Button3","Button4"]
            for index in pollOptions {
                let bt = UIButton(type: .system)
                bt.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
                bt.setTitle(index, for: .normal)
                optionBtnStackView.addArrangedSubview(bt)
            }
        }
    }
}
```